# realtime system database use

Tags: sql-server, performance, windows-ce, real-time

Given a .NET environment with Windows CE, can you persist thousands of records per second in a local database (SQL Server 2008 - standard or CE).

What are the performance issues with persisting realtime instrument data in a database versus a log file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 standard is more than capable of those insertion rates PROVIDED you have hardware capable of supporting it.

The question you really need to be asking is do I require the ability to search the captured data quickly?

This SO answer might be of interest: [What does database query and insert speed depend on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331293/what-does-database-query-and-insert-speed-depend-on)

The number (and width) of indexes on a table will obviously have an impact on insertion rate.

If you are considering open-source, then [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/topreasons.html) is often cited as being able to handle high volumes.

Comment: the feed needs to be used for realtime display.  the data storage can happen later for the sake of posterity/reproducibility and should not interfere with the realtime performance of the device.

Comment: then perhaps collect the data to log files, and periodically (in an offline process) load those files into a database....